# Angular 8 sending an array with the navigate() is returning an object instead of the array itself

Tags: angular, angular-router, angular8, angular-activatedroute

I want to send an array of data within the `.navigate()` of angular 8 routing module.

At the home component, the result of:

```
console.log(this.offers)
```

Is returning all available offers with all their related data.

After that, I am sending `this.offers` within the navigate:

```
this.router.navigate(['/offers'], {queryParams:{ 'offers': this.offers}});
```

At the offers component, I tried to get the array of offers using:

```
console.log(this.activatedRouter.snapshot.queryParams.get('offers'))
```

But the result is just `[Object Object]`.

I tried to use `this.activatedRouter.snapshot.params['offers']` but it returned the same thing.

I tried the following:

```
console.log(this.activatedRouter.snapshot.queryParamMap.get('offers'))
```

But it returned an [Object Object]:

[image]

Comment: query params are strings, inside the query string of the URL: `offers?foo=bar&baz=bing`. Trying to put JavaScript objects in query parameters doesn't make much sense.

Comment: @JbNizet so what to use instead ?

Comment: Nothing at all. Just navigate to the component, and let the component load all the available offers if it needs to display them.

Comment: I found the solution using `window state`

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `activatedRouter.snapshot`, subscribe to `this.activatedRoute.queryParams` stream which actively emits any changes in query parameters.

```
@Component({ ... })
export class MyComponent implements OnInit {
  order: string;
  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.route.queryParams
      .filter(params => params.offers)
      .subscribe(params => {
        console.log('Query Params: ', params); // {offers: <value>}
      });
  }
}
```

Comment: Can  use Params instead of queryParams ?

Answer (score 0):

There are several solutions for it according to [this link](https://medium.com/ableneo/how-to-pass-data-between-routed-components-in-angular-2306308d8255) on medium.

The one I need is using `this.navigate`.

So the solution was at the originating component:

```
this.router.navigate(['/offers'], { state: {'offers': this.offers, 'info': this.info}});
```

And at the destination component which is not a child component in my case (it could, no problem with that), we should use the `state` extras which new from angular 7.2+:

```
this.offers = window.history.state.offers;
```

We cannot use the `snapshot` or `queryParams` in this case, as according to the link above, it will be removed after `ngOnInit()` is executed. SO best solution is to use the `state` extra